# Green Lantern story with a Lantern who only has 60 seconds left on the ring...and no way to recharge it

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, green-lantern

#### I am looking for a Green Lantern story from the Bronze Age of comics to the early Modern Age (circa 1975 to 2000); a  wide swath I know, but this particular story had an unusual Green Lantern.

- I don't remember anything distinctive about this character; I am not even sure he wore a costume, and I don't have any pictures.
- **His most distinctive feature was he only had sixty seconds left on his ring. (or some other impossibly short period he was forced to make due with).**
- The entire story revolved around him using his ring for only seconds at a time with no ability to recharge it.
- What made the story strange was he was counting down the seconds and **SAVING the charge by storing the ring in a temporal bubble**, created by the ring. He was preventing the ring from being exhausted by extending its 24 hours indefinitely.

This was the most efficient use of the Power Ring I have ever seen and wanted to know if anyone had a line on the title of the story, a picture of the character or even a name I could use to do the rest of the background.

Comment: Sorry, just got off of a temp gig and brain is a little frazzled. Corrections made.

Comment: Did it involve him hallucinating that he could suddenly have an effect on yellow? Was he in battle? Anything at all about his circumstances beyond the ring discharging?

Comment: I am almost certain it isn't Hal Jordan or any well-known Lantern. Maybe from one of those "Tales of the Green Lantern Corps" specials. I think he was in some kind of wartime footing, but my memory just can't resolve it properly. I know his putting the ring in a temporal stasis was an extended measure, something really strange and creative.

Comment: That is an interesting premise, and I have no recollection of it. We can narrow it down somewhat - it seems unlikely to have been published between Emerald Twilight - 1994 and Green Lantern: Rebirth - 2004. There may have been a new Tales of The Green Lantern Corps story or two in there, but Kyle was the primary or sole GL during most of that time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Raker Qarrigat

[image: Raker Qarrigat flying off with his lantern]

You might be referring to a post-*Emerald Twilight* storyline involving Raker Qarrigat:

> One of the lone sources of light on Darkseid’s horrifying homeworld, Qarrigat lead a few unsuccessful rebellions against the tyrant. He’s kind of a Sisyphusian character, pushing against a force that will never move, but he’s got a rest for a while now that the Fourth World is MIA....
>
> The very idea of the Green Lantern of Apokolips is the kind of shared universe crossover that only really happens in super-hero comics, and thanks to creator Walt Simonson, it’s one of the best. **Even better is the idea that, thanks to “Emerald Twilight,” Raker had to seal his ring in a time bubble, relying on it only in case of emergencies lest his final 24 hour charge run out and leave him powerless to battle Jack Kirby’s ultimate evil!**
>
> ([Source](https://comicsalliance.com/the-23-brightest-and-dimmest-members-of-the-green-lantern-corps/))

The relevant issue seems to be ***Green Lantern 80-Page Giant Vol. 1 #3: A Lantern Against the Dark*** (August 2000).

Comment: Okay, you have to tell me how you did this. What was you strategy for finding this Green Lantern?

Comment: @Thaddeus : Hehe, well, "sixty seconds of charge" (or variations of it) wasn't pulling up anything, nor was "temporal bubble".  So I tried "time bubble" instead, and voila.  I kinda do remember reading this one when it came out, but not enough to have answered from memory alone.  Anyway, glad to be of help! :-)